# Does anyone use Julia programming language?

Tags: tools, julia

Is anyone using `Julia` (http://julialang.org/) for professional jobs?

Or using it instead of R, Matlab, or Mathematica?

Is it a good language?

If you have to predict next 5-10 years: Do you think it grow up enough to became such a standard in data science like R or similar?

Comment: There is no question here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I personally have used `Julia` for a good number of professional projects, and while, as Dirk mentioned, this is purely conjecture, I can give some insights on where Julia really stands out. The question of whether or not these reasons will prove enough to have `Julia` succeed as a language is anyone's guess.

- **Distributed Systems**: Julia is the easiest language I've ever dealt with in terms of building distributed systems. This is becoming more and more relevant in computing, and will potentially become a deciding factor, but the question of whether or not `Julia`'a relative ease decides this is up for debate
- **JIT Performance**: Julia's JIT compiler is extremely fast, and while there is a lot of debate as to how accurate these benchmark numbers are, the [Julia Website](http://julialang.org/) shows a series of relevant benchmarks
- **Community**: This is an area where `Julia` just isn't quite there. The community that is there is generally supportive, but not quite as knowledgable as the `R` or `python` communities, which is a definite minus.
- **Extensibility**: This is another place where `Julia` is currently lacking, there is a large disconnect between the implies code patterns that `Julia` steers you toward and what it can actually support. The type system is currently overly bulky and difficult to use effectively.

Again, can't say what this means for the future, but these are just a couple of relevant points when it comes to evaluating `Julia` in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

There is really no question here as you ask for pure conjectures but consider at least that

- this week has [Julia Con](http://juliacon.org/), the first Julia conference
- you could search GitHub and/or the registered Julia modules